# How to use vue-slider-component in Laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-slider-component

i would like to add a slider to my panel. I've insalled

```
npm install vue-slider-component --save
```

and then i created a new component and regstried in `app.js`

In my Slider.vue component i added the startet template

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-slider ref="slider" v-bind="options" v-model="value"></vue-slider>
    <h3><small>Value: </small>{{ options.value }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>
```

and imported the vueSlider

```
<script>
  import vueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'

  export default {
    components: {
      vueSlider
    },

    data() {
      return {
        options: {
          value: 5,
          width: 'auto',
          height: 6,
          direction: 'horizontal',
          dotSize: 16,
          eventType: 'auto',
          min: 5,
          max: 100,
          interval: 5,
          show: true,
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

I'm getting the the slider. Unfortunately i can't slide it and get immediately the maxValue on the start. Like in this picture
[image]
and thats it. It doesn't matter where i click it does nothing. When i would like to change the options like change the dotSize it also does nothing.

I noticed that when i open the console(F12) it's working perfectly.

The slider is wrped in a bootstrap 3 panel.

What do i'm missing ?

UPDATE 1:

i pulled the value outside the options now i get this:

[image]

Comment: Official live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2xy72dod/1240/) has `value` outside `options` object. So I think you should do the same or use `v-model="options.value"`

Comment: i updated my question. now the value is outside the options

Comment: Ok, it's not this. But your slider acts similar to first one in [fiddle linked in this exception](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component/tree/v2.5.9#exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

You should put options directly in the `<vue-slider>` as a properties. It can be dynamic if you add them in the data object.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-slider 
      :value='value'
      width='auto'
      :height='6'
      direction='horizontal'
      :dotSize="16"
      eventType='auto'
      :min='5'
      :max='100'
      :interval='5'
      :show='true'
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'    

export default {
  data: () => ({
    value: 5
  }),
  components: {
    vueSlider
  }
}
</script>
```